# MapReduce single item from streaming source against finite items from map in Hazelcast Jet

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

Being new to Hazelcast Jet, I was trying to build a setup where single item from an infinite source (i.e. a Map Journal of user requests) is MapReduced against a (possibly changing and) huge Map of reference items.

Specifically, for this example I want to determine the IDs of the vectors (read: `float[]`) of the smallest Euclidean distance in a map of vectors (the *references*), given a used-defined input vector (the *query*).

If implemented naively on a single machine, this would be going through the Map items of the references and determining the euclidean distance to the query for each of them, while keeping the k-smallest matches, where the input is taken from a user request (HTTP `POST`, button click, etc.) and the result set is available immediately after the computation finishes.

My recent approach was to:

- Listen on a map journal for the request
- `.distributed().broadcast()` the request to the mapping job
- have the mapping job obtain the `.localKeySet()` of the reference vectors
- emit the IDs of the k-smallest vectors (by euclidean distance)
- reduce/collect the results on a single node via a `.partitioned(item -> item.requestId)` partitioning
- store the results to a map on which the client has a key listener.

Conceptually here every query is a batch of size `1` and I'm actually processing batches as they come. However, I have massive troubles letting the mappers and reducers know when a batch is done so that the collectors know when they are done (so that they can emit the final result).

I tried using watermarks both with real and fake timestamps (obtained automatically via an `AtomicLong` instance) and emit from the `tryProcessWm` functions, however that seems to be a very brittle solution as some of the events are dropped. I also need to make sure no two requests are interleaved (i.e. using partitioning on the request ID), but at the same time have the mapper run on all nodes ...

How would I attack this task?

---

**Edit #1:**

Right now, my mapper looks like this:

```java
private static class EuclideanDistanceMapP extends AbstractProcessor {
    private IMap<Long, float[]> referenceVectors;

    final ScoreComparator comparator = new ScoreComparator();

    @Override
    protected void init(@Nonnull Context context) throws Exception {
        this.referenceVectors = context.jetInstance().getMap(REFERENCE_VECTOR_MAP_NAME);
        super.init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean tryProcess0(@Nonnull Object item) {
        final Tuple3<Long, Long, float[]> query = (Tuple3<Long, Long, float[]>)item;
        final long requestId = query.f0();
        final long timestamp = query.f1();
        final float[] queryVector = query.f2();

        final TreeSet<Tuple2<Long, Float>> buffer = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        for (Long vectorKey : referenceVectors.localKeySet()) {
            float[] referenceVector = referenceVectors.get(vectorKey);
            float distance = 0.0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < queryVector.length; ++i) {
                distance += (queryVector[i] - referenceVector[i]) * (queryVector[i] - referenceVector[i]);
            }

            final Tuple2<Long, Float> score = Tuple2.tuple2(vectorKey, (float) Math.sqrt(distance));
            if (buffer.size() < MAX_RESULTS) {
                buffer.add(score);
                continue;
            }

            // If the value is larger than the largest entry, discard it.
            if (comparator.compare(score, buffer.last()) >= 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise we remove the largest entry after adding the new one.
            buffer.add(score);
            buffer.pollLast();
        }

        return tryEmit(Tuple3.tuple3(requestId, timestamp, buffer.toArray()));
    }

    private static class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<Long, Float>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Tuple2<Long, Float> a, Tuple2<Long, Float> b) {
            return Float.compare(a.f1(), b.f1());
        }
    }
}
```

The reducer is essentially replicating that (minus the vector calculation, of course).

---

**Edit #2:**

Here's the DAG setup. It currently fails when there are more than a handful of concurrent requests. Most of the items are dropped due to the watermarks.

```java
DAG dag = new DAG();
Vertex sourceStream = dag.newVertex("source",
    SourceProcessors.<Long, float[], Tuple2<Long, float[]>>streamMapP(QUERY_VECTOR_MAP_NAME,
            e -> e.getType() == EntryEventType.ADDED || e.getType() == EntryEventType.UPDATED,
            e -> Tuple2.tuple2(e.getKey(), e.getNewValue()),true));

// simple map() using an AtomicLong to create the timestamp    
Vertex addTimestamps = dag.newVertex("addTimestamps", AddTimestampMapP::new);

// the class shown above.
Vertex map = dag.newVertex("map", EuclideanDistanceMapP::new);

Vertex insertWatermarks = dag.newVertex("insertWatermarks",
        insertWatermarksP((Tuple3<Long, Long, float[]> t) -> t.f1(), withFixedLag(0), emitByMinStep(1)));

Vertex combine = dag.newVertex("combine", CombineP::new);

// simple map() that drops the timestamp
Vertex removeTimestamps = dag.newVertex("removeTimestamps", RemoveTimestampMapP::new);

// Using a list here for testing.
Vertex sink = dag.newVertex("sink", SinkProcessors.writeListP(SINK_NAME));

dag.edge(between(sourceStream, addTimestamps))
    .edge(between(addTimestamps, map.localParallelism(1))
        .broadcast()
        .distributed())
    .edge(between(map, insertWatermarks).isolated())
    .edge(between(insertWatermarks, combine.localParallelism(1))
            .distributed()
            .partitioned((Tuple2<Long, Tuple2<Long, Float>[]> item) -> item.f0()))
    .edge(between(combine, removeTimestamps)
            .partitioned((Tuple3<Long, Long, Tuple2<Long, Float>[]> item) -> item.f0()))
    .edge(between(removeTimestamps, sink.localParallelism(1)));
```

---

**Edit #3:**

Here's my current combiner implementation. I assume that all items will be ordered according to the watermarks; or in general that only items of the same request will be collected by the same combiner instance. This doesn't seem to be true though ...

```java
private static class CombineP extends AbstractProcessor {
    private final ScoreComparator comparator = new ScoreComparator();
    private final TreeSet<Tuple2<Long, Float>> buffer = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    private Long requestId;
    private Long timestamp = -1L;

    @Override
    protected boolean tryProcess0(@Nonnull Object item) {
        final Tuple3<Long, Long, Tuple2<Long, Float>[]> itemTuple = (Tuple3<Long, Long, Tuple2<Long, Float>[]>)item;
        requestId = itemTuple.f0();

        final long currentTimestamp = itemTuple.f1();
        if (currentTimestamp > timestamp) {
            buffer.clear();
        }
        timestamp = currentTimestamp;

        final Object[] scores = itemTuple.f2();

        for (Object scoreObj : scores) {
            final Tuple2<Long, Float> score = (Tuple2<Long, Float>)scoreObj;

            if (buffer.size() < MAX_RESULTS) {
                buffer.add(score);
                continue;
            }

            // If the value is larger than the largest entry, discard it.
            if (comparator.compare(score, buffer.last()) >= 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise we remove the largest entry after adding the new one.
            buffer.add(score);
            buffer.pollLast();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean tryProcessWm(int ordinal, @Nonnull Watermark wm) {
        // return super.tryProcessWm(ordinal, wm);
        return tryEmit(Tuple3.tuple3(requestId, timestamp, buffer.toArray())) && super.tryProcessWm(ordinal, wm);
    }

    private static class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<Long, Float>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Tuple2<Long, Float> a, Tuple2<Long, Float> b) {
            return Float.compare(a.f1(), b.f1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "the mapping job", you mean your custom implementation of `Processor`?

Comment: Yup. I added the code for clarification.

Comment: Since you do a broadcast, do you set the local parallesim of `EuclideanDistanceMapP` to one?

Comment: To keep the best results it is more efficient to use a `PriorityQueue` (it uses the min/max heap inside). Also, you dispose of a lot of work each time you get `false` from `tryEmit`

Comment: Thanks! Java isn't my native tongue either ... I added the DAG to explain my experiment a bit more.

Comment: All your processors should have a local parallelism of one. Especially, i think you're getting dropped items due to the parallelization of `insertWatermarksP`, which introduces skew into the stream.

Comment: Another problem is your timestamping. On each member you'll slap a different timestamp on the same item because you use local `AtomicLong`s. You could have timestamped the item before sending over the distributed-broadcast edge.

Comment: My idea was to have the job run as part of the cluster and generate the timestamps close to the source. If I create them on the client I fear some of them might be flagged "late" due to race conditions when sending them to the map.

Comment: My mistake, you do timestamp them early, but you add watermarks later, with a parallelized processor. Although this shouldn't cause problems because the watermarks will be coalesced, it doesn't have any positive effect, either. In your case you could just emit the watermarks from `AddTimestampMapP` since they are strictly ordered.

Comment: Still, I'm not clear how you get things done in `CombineP`. Do you buffer all received items, grouping them by timestamp, and then process those which have fallen behind the newest watermark value (in `tryProcessWm`)?

Comment: Added the combiner. :)

Comment: Yes, you can't count on such strict order behind a distributed edge. The items are sent in batches. When you implement the low-level infrastructure like the `Processor`, you are not shielded from any disorder that happens in the processing pipeline. So you should keep a map from timestamp to combined data, and when you observe a watermark N, you can emit (and delete from map) all items with timestamp less than N.

Comment: I realize you have a fundamental issue with your timestamps. The source is distributed so each member will see some items, but the timestamp generator is local and will produce duplicate timestamps on each member. This will then break your combiner. I don't see any simple way to avoid this, unless you can rely on the sequential ID of requests instead of the timestamp.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many keys do you intend to store on each node? With this approach, you're only going to be doing the mapping on one thread in each node.

Comment: I see that as a problem too. There will be about a million keys per node.

Answer (score 1):

You must always remember that items between two vertices can be reordered. When you have parallel requests, their intermediate results can be interleaved in `CombineP`.

In `CombineP`, you can rely on the fact that the number of intermediate results is equal to the number of members in the cluster. Calculate the number of participating members in `init` from `globalParallelism / localParallelism`. When you receive this number of intermediates, you can emit the final result.

Another trick might be to run multiple requests in parallel on each member. You can achieve this by using two edges:
1. broadcast+distributed edge to a parallelism=1 processor
2. unicast edge to a parallelism=N processor

Also note that `localKeys` is not suitable for huge maps: the query size is [limited](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#localKeySet--).

Here's the code for the above. Code is for Jet 0.5:

The DAG:

```java
DAG dag = new DAG();
Vertex sourceStream = dag.newVertex("source",
        streamMapP(QUERY_VECTOR_MAP_NAME,
                e -> e.getType() == EntryEventType.ADDED || e.getType() == EntryEventType.UPDATED,
                e -> entry(e.getKey(), e.getNewValue()),true));

Vertex identity = dag.newVertex("identity", mapP(identity()))
        .localParallelism(1);
Vertex map = dag.newVertex("map", peekOutputP(EuclideanDistanceMapP::new));
Vertex combine = dag.newVertex("combine", peekOutputP(new CombineMetaSupplier()));
Vertex sink = dag.newVertex("sink", writeListP(SINK_NAME));

dag.edge(between(sourceStream, identity)
           .broadcast()
           .distributed())
   .edge(between(identity, map))
   .edge(between(map, combine)
           .distributed()
           .partitioned((Entry item) -> item.getKey()))
   .edge(between(combine, sink));
```

EuclideanDistanceMapP class:

```java
private static class EuclideanDistanceMapP extends AbstractProcessor {

    private IMap<Long, float[]> referenceVectors;
    final ScoreComparator comparator = new ScoreComparator();
    private Object pendingItem;

    @Override
    protected void init(@Nonnull Context context) throws Exception {
        this.referenceVectors = context.jetInstance().getMap(REFERENCE_VECTOR_MAP_NAME);
        super.init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean tryProcess0(@Nonnull Object item) {
        if (pendingItem == null) {
            final Entry<Long, float[]> query = (Entry<Long, float[]>) item;
            final long requestId = query.getKey();
            final float[] queryVector = query.getValue();

            final PriorityQueue<Entry<Long, Float>> buffer = new PriorityQueue<>(comparator.reversed());
            for (Long vectorKey : referenceVectors.localKeySet()) {
                float[] referenceVector = referenceVectors.get(vectorKey);
                float distance = 0.0f;

                for (int i = 0; i < queryVector.length; ++i) {
                    distance += (queryVector[i] - referenceVector[i]) * (queryVector[i] - referenceVector[i]);
                }

                final Entry<Long, Float> score = entry(vectorKey, (float) Math.sqrt(distance));
                if (buffer.size() < MAX_RESULTS || comparator.compare(score, buffer.peek()) < 0) {
                    if (buffer.size() == MAX_RESULTS)
                        buffer.remove();
                    buffer.add(score);
                }
            }
            pendingItem = entry(requestId, buffer.toArray(new Entry[0]));
        }
        if (tryEmit(pendingItem)) {
            pendingItem = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

CombineP class:

```java
private static class CombineP extends AbstractProcessor {
    private final ScoreComparator comparator = new ScoreComparator();
    private final Map<Long, PriorityQueue<Entry<Long, Float>>> buffer = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Long, Integer> accumulatedCount = new HashMap<>();
    private final int upstreamMemberCount;
    private Entry<Long, Entry<Long, Float>[]> pendingItem;

    private CombineP(int upstreamMemberCount) {
        this.upstreamMemberCount = upstreamMemberCount;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean tryProcess0(@Nonnull Object item) {
        if (pendingItem == null) {
            final Entry<Long, Entry<Long, Float>[]> localValue = (Entry<Long, Entry<Long, Float>[]>) item;
            long requestId = localValue.getKey();
            PriorityQueue<Entry<Long, Float>> globalValue = buffer.computeIfAbsent(requestId, key -> new PriorityQueue<>(comparator.reversed()));
            globalValue.addAll(asList(localValue.getValue()));
            while (globalValue.size() > MAX_RESULTS) {
                globalValue.remove();
            }
            int count = accumulatedCount.merge(requestId, 1, Integer::sum);
            if (count == upstreamMemberCount) {
                // we've received enough local values, let's emit and remove the accumulator
                pendingItem = entry(requestId, globalValue.toArray(new Entry[0]));
                Arrays.sort(pendingItem.getValue(), comparator);
                buffer.remove(requestId);
                accumulatedCount.remove(requestId);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (tryEmit(pendingItem)) {
            pendingItem = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You also need custom meta-supplier for `CombineP`:

```java
private static class CombineMetaSupplier implements ProcessorMetaSupplier {
    private int upstreamMemberCount;

    @Override
    public void init(@Nonnull Context context) {
        upstreamMemberCount = context.totalParallelism() / context.localParallelism();
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Function<Address, ProcessorSupplier> get(@Nonnull List<Address> addresses) {
        return address -> ProcessorSupplier.of(() -> new CombineP(upstreamMemberCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `globalParallelism / localParallelism` assumption hold when I add more nodes to the cluster while the job is running?

Comment: The new members will not silently start participating in the job. If the job gets rescaled to them, it will be stopped and re-run, so your initialization will run again with the new values. But to support that you have to participate in the snapshotting protocol.